# Generating non-repeating 6 numbers asking for maximum number in JS

Tags: javascript, random, numbers

Hi guys i have some code here asking for maximum number and generate 6 numbers .. but my problem is their a duplicate number generated, can someone tell me guys to correct my code...

```
function mygenerated() { 
  var rlts = document.getElementsByName("result");
  for (var i=0 ; i<=5; i++) { 
    rlts[i].value = ""; // clear results
  }
  var max = eval("document.lot.maxnum.value");
  if (max.length<1) {
    alert ("You must choose a number for the maximum value!");
    document.lot.maxnum.focus();
    return false;
  }
  for (var i=0 ; i<=5; i++) { 
    rlts[i].value = (Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1);  
  }     
}
```

at first its look good but again there is a duplicate results appear.. :(

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at this, to modify your code slightly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Getting_a_random_integer_between_two_values

Comment: Could you also provide the HTML ? The better would be a working snippet

Comment: <pre> Enter the Maximum Number Value<input name="maxnum" size="2" 
    type="text" value="49" /></div>

    <input onclick="mygenerated()" type="button" value="Generated Now" /> 
    <br />
    <br />
    <input name="result" size="2" type="text" />
    <input name="result" size="2" type="text" />
    <input name="result" size="2" type="text" />
    <input name="result" size="2" type="text" />
    <input name="result" size="2" type="text" />
    <input name="result" size="2" type="text" /></form> <code>